# Unable to configure a non java project on Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, build

I have a non-Java project for which I want to automate the build through jenkins.

I have create a job with free Style type. Then I have checked out the SVN repository to my local machine. For testing purposes, I want to first build the project locally.

I have Repository URL : `file:///C:/MyProject/`.
I get an error: Unable to access `file:///C:/MyProject` : `svn: E180001: Unable to open an ra_local session to URL`.

Also I tried with credentials, but am still getting same error.
Note: credentials I have given are the ones which I use to login to my local machine.

Please assists.

Comment: Why are you trying to pass a non-SVN URL to SVN? If you want a local build, set the SCM option to "None" and copy the relevant source code in to your workspace.

Comment: Hi Chris, If we select 'None' option in SCM, where do we provide our local workspace path, can you please guide a bit in details, since i am new in this field

Comment: You don't need to change the workspace path. Simply before you start your build add a build step that copies the stuff you want to build from `C:/MyProject/` in to `%WORKSPACE%`.